# Let Visual Studio show default/current acccess modifier in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, access-modifiers

When hovering over a field or method etc. in Visual Studio, there's a popup showing the access modifier using a symbol, e.g. for

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
```

and the `Main` method it shows

[image]

because `Main` is private. Is it possible to let Visual Studio (I am on 2019) show the access modifier without having to hover a given field/method? Maybe similar to the number of references?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything you can setup directly in Visual Studio.

There is a way how to provide such a visual output by creating CodeLens. You may want to search Visual Studio Marketplace for existing, before you create a new one.

[Code Lens OOP Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/CodeLensOopSample)